# how to create regular expression which not allow semi colon, colon single quote and double quote

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

i am trying to create a regular expression which is not allow semi colon, colon single quote and double quote

```
var address=/^[\u0022\u0027\u003A\u003B]{1,50}$/
```

address.test(value);

this my code

this code is run only when textbox contain only ; : ' "

if ;123 this code is not run

please help me

Comment: if i am using this code '"]+$/ show in red color

Comment: now this code is in red color '"]{1,50}$/

Comment: Sana, please edit your question so it reflects EVERYTHING & EXACTLY what you need.
Also, a link to what you have tried so far helps.

Comment: rob this code is not working still the same problem

Comment: Then your requirements are wrong. The provided RegEx follows the rules at the first line in your question.

Comment: i have a string if string contain ' " ; : then error message is show

Answer (score 2):

Add a circumflex (^) character after the opening bracket ([), to indicate negation (“any character but…”):

```
var address=/^[^\u0022\u0027\u003A\u003B]{1,50}$/
```

Without it, the expression tests that the value is a string containing *only* the characters that you actually wish to *exclude*.